# Ressources for CSS styles suitable for Knitr-markdown output?

Tags: css, r, markdown, knitr

I am looking for a ressource where I can download CSS styles suitable for Rstudio/knitr markdown output?

The default look of the default CSS-style is fine, but I would like to find a CSS style where the content is positioned in the middle of the screen.

- something like this (ignore content, colors, sidebar etc):
  http://www.barackobama.com/news/
- not like this (which is similar to the default):
  http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/Normal.html

I don't really know CSS so I can't do it myself. I have tried to change the margin in the default CSS style from 0px to 200 px:

```
body, td {
   font-family: sans-serif;
   background-color: white;
   font-size: 16px;
   margin: 200px;

}
```

The problem with this "solution" is that it only works when the browser window is maximized, and pdf printed from the browser are too narrow also.

edit: This is good:
https://gist.github.com/andyferra/2554919

edit2: The preview version of Rstudio ( RStudio 0.98.932 - Windows XP/Vista/7/8) has a nice default CSS. Get it here: http://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/

edit3: The newest version of Rstudio now includes some very nice CSS-styles to choose from :) http://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not just a CSS resource, but you can take a look at the `knitrBootstrap` project, which provides a way to convert Rmarkdown to HTML styled with the bootstrap framework, including a CSS style chooser and some fancy javascript add-ons :

https://github.com/jimhester/knitrBootstrap

Comment: The knitrBootstrap is really an amazing package.

Comment: Do you know how to disable the menu?

Comment: @RasmusLarsen Look at the `choose` option of the `knit_bootstrap_md` function, IIRC.